# How can I sort a list of args in Sympy

Tags: python, sympy

I have a an expression, i.e. `6*x**3 + 2*x**(1/2)` and want to select the item with the lowest exponent, in this case `2*x**(1/2)`. Is there a simple way to do that? Working with `args` gives an unsorted list of items and working with `Poly` is not possible here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using [`as_ordered_terms`](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/core.html#sympy.core.expr.Expr.as_ordered_terms) and [`as_coeff_exponent`](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/core.html#sympy.core.expr.Expr.as_coeff_exponent) with [`min`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#min):

```
>>> from sympy import symbols
>>> x = symbols('x')
>>> expr = 6*x**3 + 2*x**(1/2)
>>> terms = expr.as_ordered_terms()
>>> lowest_term = min(terms, key=lambda term: term.as_coeff_exponent(x)[1])
>>> lowest_term
2*x**0.5
```

Answer (score 1):

```py
>>> eq = 6*x**3 + 2*sqrt(x)
>>> d = eq.as_coefficients_dict().items()
>>> sorted(d, key=lambda _:_[0].as_base_exp()[1])
[(sqrt(x), 2), (x**3, 6)]
```

Comment: Hello smichr, this is an elegant answer, but the coeffs do not remain

Comment: Now modified to do so.